# Repositioning UIWindow after Rotating it

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cgaffinetransform, uiwindow

Recently I made a custom Alert which is a subclass of `UIWindow`. I'm trying to rotate the alert when the `UIViewController` is in landscape orientation. I'm able to rotate it successfully, however I'm having trouble repositioning it so that its origin is in the upper left corner of the screen. I have the following code below:

```
    CGRect mainScreenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, mainScreenBounds.size.width, mainScreenBounds.size.height);
    }
    else
    {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, mainScreenBounds.size.height, mainScreenBounds.size.width);

        if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
        {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, M_PI / 2);
        }
        else
        {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, -M_PI / 2);
        }
        self.center = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width / 2, self.bounds.size.height / 2);
    }
```

Setting the `center` doesn't seem to do anything for whatever reason. Does anyone have any clue on what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score -6):

*[2013 answer]* You *should* not have more than one UIWindow in an application. There is already one. Reimplement, subclassing from UIView.

From the [UIWindow](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html) docs: "Unless an app can display content on an external device screen, an app has only one window."

---

Edit… 8 years later: You've always been able to create multiple windows; previously you were guided against it.

As mentioned below in the comments, Apple's advice on windows has changed. I'd suggest seeking a solution with views / view controllers instead of trying to use a window.

Updated docs:

> Most apps need only one window, which displays the app’s content on the device’s main screen. Although you can create additional windows on the device’s main screen, extra windows are commonly used to display content on an external screen…
> You also use UIWindow objects for a handful of other tasks…

> You should rarely need to subclass UIWindow. The kinds of behaviors you might implement in a window can usually be implemented in a higher-level view controller more easily.

Also, the window is has no visible representation. It doesn't need repositioning (per the original question). The views inside it need to be repositioned.

Comment: I need a UIWindow so I can place it over the status bar like a UIAlertView.

Comment: if you want the status bar gone, set it to go away

Comment: Don't want it gone, you know how when an alert comes up it puts a black tint over the screen? That's what I'm going for and need a UIWindow for that.

Comment: either you can do that with a UIView (correctly resized, reparented), or forgo dimming the status bar - walk up the view hierarchy in the debugger and see what's there

Comment: Apple does not restrict having multiple UIWindows in an app, in fact their UIAlertView is a UIWindow. I think it's fine to include it as an alert. Doing it as a UIView won't put it over the status bar which I want to happen to the let the user know that the rest of the UI is disabled.

Comment: That is incorrect, [UIAlertView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) is a subclass of `UIView`. And, as stated above, the docs state only one window per device (per app, is implied).

Comment: I have seen some custom `UIAlertView`-type code that keeps other things from being touched by creating its own event loop and managing all UI until the user touches one of its buttons, then exits back to the main even loop.

Comment: I realise this is quite old, but for anyone else coming here, I'd like to reiterate that you CAN have multiple UIWindow's in an app, and in fact the UIAlertView, while is a UIView itself, does display in a separate UIWindow. In order to display content above certain views you will NEED to have a separate UIWindow. Try displaying a view over a UIPopoverController.